# Query all username fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I know this is a very basic question but I have done hours of research and I can't find it anywhere so maybe it's also useful for other people.

I just downloaded MongoDB Compass because I'm trying to export all `username` from my `account` collection and there's no way I can create a query that returns **only** the username field.

How can I, with MongoDB, get all the values of a specific field?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try projection as `db.collection('account').find({}, {username: true})`?

Comment: simply use 1 in front of the field name to project it, `db.collection('your_collection_name').find({}, { "your_field_name": 1 })`, thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Projection**.

Where you can add or remove Field in results of data.

Try

`db.collection.find({}, { user_name : 1})`

Where 1 is true and 0 is false.

Answer (score 0):

This will return only user_name field from all documents

```
db.collection.find({}, {"_id": 0, "user_name": 1})
```